# Passing anonymous structures to functions as parameter using C++

Tags: c++, structure

So.. I'm working on a project using C++ and I have multiple structures and I have only one fuction that need to have one of that structures as a parameter.

I already searched everywhere and I only found examples with one structure in specific...

Here is one of my structures

```
struct {
  int tag_id;
  String serial;
} dataHeader;
```

And here where I pass it

`loraSend(message, &dataHeader);`

And here is the function that will receive the struct as a parameter
 `void loraSend(String message, struct MsgStruct &msg_struct)`

```
The problem is that this is just giving this error: "no matching function for call to 'loraSend(String&, <anonymous struct>*)' ".
```

Can you explain to me how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is `MsgStruct` a template parameter?

Comment: MsgStruct is just a struct that I put in the function, and use it to do this "LoRa.write((uint8_t*)(&msg_struct), sizeof(msg_struct));", because I have multiple structures to send in that Write, I want to pass them as a parameter, that's why  I put the MsgStruct there

Comment: Note that there are no anonymous structs in C++. This is an unnamed struct.

Comment: What's the difference between an anonymous struct and an unnamed struct? Those seem like two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
using MsgStruct = decltype(dataHeader);


void loraSend(String message, MsgStruct* msg_struct) {
   // ...
}


// elsewhere:
loraSend(message, &dataHeader);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, and correct me if I'm wrong, you are saying that the MsgStruct will be the type of dataHeader. Imagine that I have another structure called "dataBody" and I want to pass that dataBody to "loraSend" function. I need to make another 
```using MsgStruct = decltype(dataBody);``` ?

Comment: @ACasal `MsgStruct` is going to be an alias for type of `dataHeader`. You can only have one alias called `MsgStruct` inside the same scope.

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a parameter of type `struct dataHeader` to a functions that accepts a second parameter of type `struct MsgStruct`. That is why you are getting an error message.
Your function `loraSend` could be overloaded (i.e., write another copy of it with a second parameter type of `struct MsgStruct`) or alternately, your second parameter could be a `void` pointer (which can point to anything) and `loraSend` would need to figure out its parameter type.

Comment: `dataHeader` isn't a type, it's the name of the variable whose type is an anonymous `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ does not support anonymous structs, but it does support anonymous unions.
So I don't see the reason why you shouldn't do:

```
struct MsgStruct {
  int tag_id;
  String serial;
} dataHeader;
```

Instead of `typedef` or `using` declarations.

---

The structure

```
struct {
  int tag_id;
  String serial;
} dataHeader;
```

Is an [unnamed ([class.pre])](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.pre#1) struct:

> A class-specifier whose class-head omits the class-head-name defines
> an unnamed class.

An example of an anonymous struct would be:

```
struct {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

Compiling the above with `-pedantic` should state that anonymous struct is not iso c++, however some compilers have extensions for it.

Comment: C++ *does* support anonymous structs. OP's code is legal.

Comment: OP's code shows an unnamed struct and not an anonymous struct; ISO c++ prohibits anonymous structs.

Comment: Apparently this compiler calls it an anonymous struct.

Comment: Yes it says "anonymous" but I forgot to say and don't know if it is relevant or not, but I'm using Arduino IDE! And actually the DEV C++ calls to it anonymous too 
```[Warning] anonymous type with no linkage used to declare variable '<anonymous struct> dataHeader' with linkage```